# Select2 set multiple selected options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I've been searching for solutions to solve the follow problem, however previous questions I've read have yielded no successful results.

I have a JSON encoded array stored in a database, for example `["2",2,5]`. I need to cut the first value off the array and use the remaining items to select specific options in a multiple select from select2. My current solution show below displays the option corresponding to first value of the remaining array, but not the second. Any suggestions?

```
$("#sltETags").select2({ placeholder: 'Select a Primary Tag', minimumResultsForSearch: 8}).select2('val', [<?php $LstTags = json_decode($row["Tags"]); for($i = 1; $i < count($LstTags); $i++){ if($i != count($LstTags)-1){ echo '"'.$LstTags[$i].'",'; } else { echo '"'.$LstTags[$i].'"'; }} ?>]);
```

**Outcome**

```
$("#sltETags").select2({ placeholder: 'Select a Primary Tag', minimumResultsForSearch: 8}).select2('val', ["2","5"]);
```

**HTML Code**

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Secondary Tags" id="sltETags">
    <?php
    $LstTags = $TagManager->displayTags(0);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($LstTags); $i++){
        ?><option value="<?php echo $LstTags[$i][0]; ?>"><?php echo $LstTags[$i][1]; ?></option><?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was the Javascript function to change the selected items. My fix is below:

```
            <?php

                $LstTags = json_decode($row["Tags"]);

                for($i = 1; $i < count($LstTags); $i++){
                    $LstTags[$i] = "$LstTags[$i]";
                }

                $LstTags = json_encode($LstTags);

            ?>
            $("#sltETags").select2({ placeholder: 'Select a Primary Tag', minimumResultsForSearch: 8});
            $("#sltETags").val(<?php echo $LstTags; ?>).select2();
```